# Outlook Web-AddIn Authorization, Security Warning

Tags: outlook, outlook-web-addins

[image]

When I go to Authorize?Login, A user in the desktop outlook Web-Add-In I get this image above.  This is happening in my desktop app not in the web version.  It is asking me to do I want do this. 
I think this is happening becuase I have a javascript timer set in the background to check to see a authenticated cookie is present before asking the user to login again.

I tried using Office Authorization dialog boxes but they are not working correctly.

Outlook 2016, Exchange 2016

ALso 1 more question in the outlook desk top is there a way to see a console so I can see some of my logging I have created?

So the what I am working on is the ability for a user to login into our system, store a valid token, and the user can then record email messages into our system to track communications between them and the person doing the email.

So I ask them to log into our OAuth server, Outlook would store that token, and every time the user wanted to recorded a message they would simple press a button.

Comment: The dialog seems to be coming from IE. Did you try the addin in Outlook Web in IE browser? You might get a similar error as you are trying to navigate between security zones.

When you mention Authorization Dialog Boxes, did you mean you are trying to use displayDIalogAsync? What is the issue that you are running into when using them?

Comment: To debug addins in desktop you can follow instructions here: https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/testing/debug-add-ins-using-f12-developer-tools-on-windows-10

You can also attach Visual Studio to the IEProcess and debug Script. 

Or Right click and Attach Debugger if they have a debugger installed

Comment: Outlook will not store the token for you, you can provide an addinCommand button with just a function to be able to trigger your action. You would need to store it in your own backend. You can also consider storing it in Roaming Settings:https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/1.5/Office.context?product=outlook which is per addin per user